# php sql while loop only inserting last record

Tags: php, mysql

Using the following code, only the last record is being inserted into the database. However, if I echo the data in the loop it echos all records and echoing $i shows it incrementing. Kinda new to mysql so any suggestions are welcome

```
while($i <= $num_to_enter){
$name[$i] = $_POST['name'][$i];
$lname[$i] = $_POST['lname'][$i];
$email[$i] = $_POST['email'][$i];
$phone[$i] = $_POST['pfirst'][$i].$_POST['psecond'][$i].$_POST['pthird'][$i];
$skill[$i] = $_POST['skill_level'][$i];
$sex[$i] = $_POST['sex'][$i];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `" . $mytable . "` (
`FirstName`,
 `LastName`,
 `email`,
 `phone`,
 `SkillLevel`,
 `sex`

) VALUES (
'$name[$i]',
 '$lname[$i]',
 '$email[$i]',
 '$phone[$i]',
 '$skill[$i]',
 '$sex[$i]'
);";
 $i++;
}
```

Comment: your posted code shows the query string but nothing in there is actually executing the query. I suspect your `mysql_query` or equivalent is located AFTER your loop and consequently only executing the last value of `$sql`. You need to put the `mysql_query` or equivalent IN the loop

Comment: You should NOT use mysql_query inside your loop.

Comment: We'd be amiss not to mention the SQL-injection risk in your code. These values are currently going directly from the user into your query. They should be escaped or you should explore prepared statements.

Comment: Yes I will add escape! for now it's just me testing and building :)

Comment: Chris  Please explain the reason for not using mysql_query inside a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while($i <= $num_to_enter){
$name[$i] = $_POST['name'][$i];
$lname[$i] = $_POST['lname'][$i];
$email[$i] = $_POST['email'][$i];
$phone[$i] = $_POST['pfirst'][$i].$_POST['psecond'][$i].$_POST['pthird'][$i];
$skill[$i] = $_POST['skill_level'][$i];
$sex[$i] = $_POST['sex'][$i];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `" . $mytable . "` (
`FirstName`,
 `LastName`,
 `email`,
 `phone`,
 `SkillLevel`,
 `sex`

) VALUES (
'$name[$i]',
 '$lname[$i]',
 '$email[$i]',
 '$phone[$i]',
 '$skill[$i]',
 '$sex[$i]'
);";
mysql_query($sql);

 $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> only the last record is being inserted into the database

Are you sure ? You are not even running `mysqli_query($conn,$sql)` anywhere on the code.

Comment: Crayon Violent and Shankar Damodaran  Thanks for the heads up both of you! Let me try that. Oh, Yes the last record does get entered!?? after the loop I have   if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
     {
   mysql_close($con);
some error message
    } else {
   mysql_close($con);
   success message
  }

Comment: yesm, but your loop is constantly overwriting your $sql string with a new one, so you end up only executing the LAST defined string. You need to put mysql_query() INSIDE the loop.

Comment: @MarcB, That is correct and it will solve the OPs problem, but do you `really` think this will be a good idea ?

Comment: nope. but I'm getting tired of pointing out sql injection problems to people who obviously couldn't care less about doing their job properly.

Comment: Shankar Damodaran and Marc B and everyone else, Thank you for all the quick responses and helpful advice! everyone on this site is great!

Comment: Marc B Yes I will add escape! for now it's just me testing and building :) much appreciated though cause I'm an old man and may have forgotten to do it!!

Answer (score 0):

you're defining the sql query but you're not executing it, try changing your code to this:

```
while($i <= $num_to_enter){
$name[$i] = $_POST['name'][$i];
$lname[$i] = $_POST['lname'][$i];
$email[$i] = $_POST['email'][$i];
$phone[$i] = $_POST['pfirst'][$i].$_POST['psecond'][$i].$_POST['pthird'][$i];
$skill[$i] = $_POST['skill_level'][$i];
$sex[$i] = $_POST['sex'][$i];

$sql = "INSERT INTO `" . $mytable . "` (
 `FirstName`,
 `LastName`,
 `email`,
 `phone`,
 `SkillLevel`,
 `sex`

) VALUES (
'$name[$i]',
 '$lname[$i]',
 '$email[$i]',
 '$phone[$i]',
 '$skill[$i]',
 '$sex[$i]'
);";
 mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
 $i++;
}
```